# display 3 different bootstrap info icon on change function menu

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an odd bug where all I am trying to do is display a tooltip depending on what is selected in the change function (also the tooltip info is different for each). The menu only has 3 possible choices.
Seems like show/hiding the tooltip does not work correctly so I resorted to using the css opacity property. This only works for one and not the other. Any one knows why this is so complicated to do on a on change function? and how do I make this work correctly. I am just simply trying to show the matching tooltip for each option of the menu.

```js
$('#menu1').change(function() {
                                                        if ($(this).val() == 'newhire') { // or this.value == '1'

                                                          
                                                            $("#iconNH").css({
                                                                opacity: 1.5
                                                            });
                                                            $("#iconUp").css({
                                                                opacity: 0.0
                                                            })
                                                           $("#iconNH").show();
                                                           $("#iconUp").hide();
                                                           

                                                        }
                                                        if ($(this).val() == 'upskill') { // or this.value == '2'

                                                          $("#iconNH").show();
                                                            $("#iconUp").css({
                                                                opacity: 1.5
                                                            });
                                                             $("#iconUp").hide();
                                                             $("#iconNH").css({
                                                                opacity: 0.0
                                                            });
                                                            

                                                        }
                                                        if ($(this).val() == 'both') { // or this.value == '3'
                                                           
                                                            $("#box5").show();
                                                            $("#iconNH").hide();

                                                        } else if ($(this).val() == '') {
                                                           
                                                            $("#iconNH").hide();
                                                             $("#iconUp").hide()
                                                        }
                                                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="menu1">
                                                        <option id="Option1" value=""></option>
                                                        <option value="newhire">New Hire</option>
                                                        <option value="upskill">Upskill</option>
                                                        <option value="both">Both</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <a id="iconNH" style="margin-right:200px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="New Hire audience availability"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>

<a id="iconUp" style="margin-right:200px;" data-toggle="tooltip" title="New Hire audience availability"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: iconNH, iconUp are two bootstrap info icons. I just want to show one on the section that it relates to. This is normally a simple task, but I am having issues showing and hiding, So i tried using the css properties to hide and show. Well, that worked only for the first one. Any ideas why its hard to show and hide a bootstrap info- icon? It is a tooltip as well